# Google custom search code does not return the result of google.com

Tags: google-search

I have generated a code from [Google custom search](http://www.google.co.in/cse/create/new) .

I want to fetch the results for a keyword exactly same as the results on `www.google.com` So I put `www.google.com` in sites to search textfield and english is the language and then create the code.

But when I am using this code and fetching results on my websites these results are different from `google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but there's no workarounds for this, custom search is different in terms of results for many reasons. Checkout:

[**Custom Search vs Google.com**](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2633385)

> In this case, however, your results are unlikely to match those
>   returned by Google Web Search, for several reasons:
>
> Your custom search engine doesn't include Google Web Search features
>   such as Oneboxes, real-time results, universal search, social feaures,
>   or personalized results.